# UITableViewCell like Clock App on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I wanted to do the same design as the clock app on iOS for my UITableView, but don't really know the different steps. So in my app I have a UITabBarController, my second tab contains a UINavigationController that loads a UITableViewController (exactly like on the screenshot below).

So for example, if I have 3 cells only, I just want to have 3 cells and not others under, and see a custom image in background (like this blue stripes or the world map in the Clock App).

[image: UITableviewController Clock App]

I have the background for the cells already (gray background on the Clock app above).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually didn't ask a question. Anyway to do the thing on screenshot you need to set background of `UINavigationController` to desirable and set `UITableViewController` tableView background color to `clearColor`. Also you need to set separator color of tableView to `clearColor`. If your cells is not full a screen you will not see other cells.

Comment: I didn't ask a question because I just wanted advices on how to make such an interface. And you responded very clearly, so that's what I wanted. Thank you @sherilyn!

Comment: And do you know how I could do for reflection on top and bottom and the first and last cell? It is a really cool effect.

Comment: what do you mean about reflection, i don't see any reflections on the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, a gradient. You can see one at the top and bottom and the table view (dark to clear color). On the screenshot, you can see the bottom one after the third cell: the cell is gray, the background is blue, and you can see this little gradient black to clear color really cool.